# Yup condition validation - single field with object values

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik, yup

I am stuck somewhere in react typescript. I am creating a form with conditional validation with Yup and formik, everything is working fine in browser but in my visual studio code showing me an error on one line:

```
["debtProfile", "taxDispute"]
```

error is : Type 'string' is not assignable to type '[string, string]'.

my validation object is this:

```
const formValidationSchema = Yup.object().shape<checkValidation>(
    {
      firstName: Yup.string()
        .min(2, "Too Short!")
        .max(50, "Too Long!")
        .required("Required"),
      lastName: Yup.string()
        .min(2, "Too Short!")
        .max(50, "Too Long!")
        .required("Required"),
      email: Yup.string().email().required("Required"),
      phone: Yup.string().required("Required"),
      province: Yup.string().required("Select Province"),
      city: Yup.string().required("Select City"),
      taxDispute: Yup.number().when(
        "debtProfile",
        (debtProfile: any, field: any) => {
          if (debtProfile[0][0].program) {
            return field;
          } else {
            return Yup.number().required();
          }
        }
      ),
      debtProfile: Yup.array().when(
        "taxDispute",
        (taxDispute: any, field: any) => {
          if (taxDispute != "") {
            return field;
          } else {
            return Yup.array(
              Yup.object({
                program: Yup.string().required("kindly select Program"),
                year: Yup.string().required("kindly select Year"),
                amount: Yup.string().required("kindly enter any amount"),
              })
            );
          }
        }
      ),
    },
    ["debtProfile", "taxDispute"]
  );
```

last line showing error that is why I cant not build, kindly help I am stuck here from 3 days.

Comment: Can you make an example here? https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-cloud-c6cyrq

Comment: Hi Paulo,
here is the sandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-firefly-g2mqh9?file=/src/App.tsx
validation also not working, kindly help me about this issue
thank alot.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the docs [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup#objectshapefields-object-nosortedges-arraystring-string-schema), the array is a value of the `noSortEdges` key in the object. I think if you change that line to be `noSortEdges: ["debtProfile", "taxDispute"]` it will work.